# Using custom fonts in react native with font family name instead of file name

Tags: react-native, fonts

**Problem:**

I have font separated to 2 files, like "XSansRegular.ttf" and "XSansBold.ttf", both has same font family, like "X Sans".

I have added it as assets.

But when I'm trying to use them with setting:

```
style={{
    fontFamily: "X Sans"
}}
```

it doesn't work. I need to use exact file name, like this:

```
style={{
    fontFamily: "XSansRegular"
}}
```

**What I want to do:**

Use it with font name, instead of file name

```
style={{
    fontFamily: "X Sans"
}}
```

with possibility to pass there props like bold

```
style={{
    fontFamily: "X Sans",
    fontWeight: 'bold'
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have the linked font files ?

If your react-native version >= 0.70，Run `npx react-native-asset` to link font files and try again.